# how to set headers for curl in php when using xampp

Tags: php, curl

```
    $headerSet=array(
                    'GET'.$url, 
                    'Host: verify-email.org',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Proxy-Connection: Close',
                    'Cookie: __utma=67582614.1178183750.1396541997.1396541997.1396550804.2; __utmz=67582614.1396541997.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atuvc=3%7C14; b38b8c1b3d6a4a2d4cc2696153b7cd63=lv63r03hdfq0p66ohv13brhlq5; __utmb=67582614.2.10.1396550804; __utmc=67582614',
                    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
                    'Connection: keep-alive',
                    'DNT: 1'                        
                    );

    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL 
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
```

Now after adding this code I tried running my program and am still not getting the headers set.
I have checked in httpsfox as well. The host is localhost but I want the host  set to verify-email.org

Comment: _“I have checked in httpsfox as well”_ – that is a _client-side_ tool, how would you possible debug a _server-side_ request with that? Are you sure that you know what is actually going on there, and how HTTP works …?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'GET'.$url,` from the header array. and place the url inside the `curl_init`

```
$ch = curl_init($url); // <- url is placed here, and it will be GET by default
```

And I didn't see you setting the `$headerSet` with your curl. Do it like this way:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerSet);
```